# How to use border to get below div design

Tags: html, css

can you please help to get the below output in div using css. if you can customize more it will be much more help full.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this using Flexbox:

```css
body {
  padding: 5%;
}

.back-div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-top: -45px;
  text-align: center;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="back-div">
  <div class="blue">
    <h1> Text 1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="yellow">
    <h1> Text 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdzgsxg4/